# How to save validation result of YOLOv8 model?

Tags: csv, validation, image-segmentation, yolov8

I have used a custom dataset that contains multiple instances in each images using YOLOv8 model and then trying to save the validation result in a csv file with this command:

```
%cd {HOME}

!yolo task=detect mode=val model={HOME}/runs/segment/train2/weights/best.pt data={dataset.location}/data.yaml > validation_results.csv
```

which returns me an empty CSV file with this name. How can I actually get these consoled results in a CSV?

The CSV file should contains the information that was shown in the consolde[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udLFE.jpg)